# .NET - Is there a way to programmatically fill all tables in a strongly-typed dataset?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, reflection, ado.net, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a SQL Server database for which I have created a strongly-typed DataSet (using the DataSet Designer in Visual Studio 2008), so all the adapters and select commands and whatnot were created for me by the wizard.

It's a small database with largely static data, so I would like to pull the contents of this DB in its entirety into my application at startup, and then grab individual pieces of data as needed using LINQ.  Rather than hard-code each adapter Fill call, I would like to see if there is a way to automate this (possibly via Reflection).

So, instead of:

```
Dim _ds As New dsTest
dsTestTableAdapters.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(_ds.Table1)
dsTestTableAdapters.Table2TableAdapter.Fill(_ds.Table2)
<etc etc etc>
```

I would prefer to do something like:

```
Dim _ds As New dsTest
For Each tableName As String In _ds.Tables
    Dim adapter as Object = <routine to grab adapter associated with the table>
    adapter.Fill(tableName)
Next
```

Is that even **remotely** doable?  I have done a fair amount of searching, and I wouldn't think this would be an uncommon request, but I must be either asking the wrong question, or I'm just weird to want to do this.

I will admit that I usually prefer to use unbound controls and not go with strongly-typed datasets (I prefer to write SQL directly), but my company wants to go this route, so I'm researching it.  I think the idea is that as tables are added, we can just refresh the DataSet using the Designer in Visual Studio and not have to make too many underlying DB code changes.

Any help at all would be most appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting.... Doing this has never even occurred to me. I'd bet it's doable but I've never gone this route. I just wanted to comment that this is an interesting way of looking at the issue. +1 to you for original thought!  Although I don't really understand the advantage of pulling in all data up front instead of just getting it as needed.  I take it this is an environment with only one user at a time so you don't have to worry about data concurrency?

Comment: There is a possibility that multiple users will be using this application simultaneously, but the data in question is read-only, so I do not believe concurrency is an issue (plus the data will be more or less static, so we don't even need to worry about dirty reads).  

As for original thinking, I'm very anti-hard-code about anything, and it galls me to have to type in something twice, when I think that some sort of automated solution would work better.

Thanks for the +1!  This is my first foray into a points-based forum, so I'm still very much a n00b.  Glad you're going easy on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not exists any api that lets you do this auto-fill of the entire typed-dataset or no such code is generated within typed-dataset that supports this. It is also difficult to do this because TableAdapters do not have a common base-class that can let you do this.

If you really need to do this, you'll have to maintain a collection of DataTable type-names and TableAdapter type-names and iterate over the collection to perform the dataset fill.

So I recommend to fill dataset for each table in 'hard-code' manner as your first code examples states.

## EDIT

Here's one possible solution.

Define an Interface ITableAdapter as following

```
public interface ITableAdapter<TDataTable> : where TDataTable : DataTable
{
    TDataTable SelectAll();
}
```

All TableAdapters are partial classes, so you can extend them and add your custom code in partial custom class for TableAdapter. Implement ITableAdapter on each TableAdapter in your typed-data-set. so it might look like this.

```
public partial class YourTableAdapter : ITableAdapter<YourDataSet.YourDataTableDataTable>
{
    public YourDataSet.YourDataTableDataTable SelectAll()
    {
         return this.GetData();
    }
}
```

Now, you can iterate over each type in your assembly and filter those of type ITableAdapter and call SelectAll() method on each of them fill it into your Dataset. :)

## EDIT2

I just came up with another elegant solution for this problem. All you need to do is define the Interface ITableAdapter to map the already implemented methods in TableAdapters that are generated by the dataset-designer.

```
public interface ITableAdapter<TDataTable> : where TDataTable : DataTable
{
    void Fill(TDataTable);
}
```

And extend your TableAdapter partial classes like this.

```
public partial class YourTableAdapter : ITableAdapter<YourDataSet.YourDataTableDataTable>
{
    //No code required here, since Fill method is already defined in TableAdapter :)
}
```

Comment: Well, if I have to, I will, certainly; you gotta do what you gotta do.  However, I have worked out the code to grab the names of all of the table adapters via a LINQ query in GetExecutingAssembly.GetTyes(); I just need to take it a step further and instantiate them.  I think.  :-).  You are right in that there is no common base class (I thought I might have had something with the TableAdapterManager, but that was for Hierarchical updates, not basic reads.  Oh well).  I'm still new at this, and this isn't the answer I was looking for, but thanks for the speedy reply!  I can't vote up yet, tho.

Comment: Ah!  That's a very elegant solution!  I'll give it a try on Monday (code's at work), but that sounds like a happy medium between hard-coding and total reflection madness, so I'm going to roll with it.  Alas, I do not have enough reputation (being very new) to vote it up, but if I could, I'd give it a +1.  Thanks!

Comment: Better and better.  I haven't tried it yet, but seeing as my reputation is now above 15, I can vote this puppy up.  Very cool.  Thanks!

Comment: Curiously awaiting result of your experiment! :)

Comment: Working on it now.  Just need to work out the VB equivalent of your statements, above.  :-)

Comment: Hmm. OK, there does not appear to be a VB equivalent of the where generic type constraint that C# uses. Not sure if there is any way to produce equivalent behavior in VB. 

And I noticed that the DataSet Designer created the Fill function as an Integer, so I changed that. The compiler does not seem to recognize that the function is being implemented, despite the signatures being as close as possible (well, minus the overloads, overridable and other keywords). I'll have to keep tinkering.

Comment: I realized that I had not followed up on this.__curious_geek's suggestion, and I do apologize.  I ultimately decided to go with my solution, because while this was a very elegant solution, the first time I added a field to a table and had to regenerate the dataset, all the custom code I had applied got wiped out.  Whoops.  So, laziness FTW.  :-)  But I still think your idea was very cool.

Answer (score 3):

I saw all above solutions and they all are good, they inspired me to find my solution, 
I made a more squeezed one, I know this is an old post, but I hope it helps people in the time to come,

```
Private Sub FillDataSet(ByRef ds As SvuDS)
    For Each t As DataTable In ds.Tables

        Dim adType As Type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetType("ProjectNameSpace.MyDSTableAdapters." & t.TableName & "TableAdapter")

        'Create Adapter Instance     
        Dim adapter As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(adType)

        'Fill the Table   
        adapter.GetType().GetMethod("Fill").Invoke(adapter, New Object() {t})
    Next
End Sub
```

I could've even inferred the namespace somehow too, but I wanted it to be simple, and it worked for me

Comment: Simple, yet elegant.  Good deal.  And upon you be peace (yeah, I know, your salutation got edited out, but I saw it before it did, and wanted to return the favor.  :-) )

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I have this worked out, and just want to share the results on the off chance that there are people out there who are as insane as I am.

Basically, all the magic happens using a couple of LINQ queries and reflection.  For the purposes of this example, we will assume:

1. There is a strongly-typed DataSet created using the DataSet Designer in Visual Studio 2008, called **dsTest**. A module-level variable holds an instance of this DataSet and is called (appropriately enough), **m_DataSet**.
2. The tables themselves all follow a standard SQL Server naming convention, starting with "tbl".
3. As a part of this wizard, a series of table adapters were created for each table inside a namespace called **dsTestTableAdapters**.
4. Each adapter is named according to the table (so if we have "tblThingy", then an adapter named "tblThingyTableAdapter" would be created).
5. The application is in a namespace called, for lack of anything better, **MyNamespace**.

Here's the routine, called on Form Load:

```
Private Sub PopulateDataSet()
    ' Get our table adapters
    Dim adapters As List(Of Type) = (From t As Type In System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetTypes Where t.Namespace = "MyNameSpace.dsTestTableAdapters" And t.Name.StartsWith("tbl") Select t).ToList

    ' Initialize our dataset
    m_DataSet = New dsUtility

    ' Get our table names
    Dim tableNames as List(Of String) = (From dtbl As DataTable In m_DataSet.Tables Select dtbl.TableName).ToList

    ' Loop through each table name and fill the table with the corresponding adapter
    For Each iter As String In tableNames
        ' Grab the corresponding adapter name 
        Dim tableName As String = iter ' Grab a copy of the table name to avoid LINQ issues with iteration variables
        Dim adapterType As Type = (From t As Type In adapters Where t.Name.StartsWith(tableName) Select t).First

        ' Given the adapter type name, use Reflection to create an instance
        Dim adapter As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(adapterType)

        ' Use the instance to fill the appropriate table
        adapter.Fill(m_DataSet.Tables(tableName))
    Next
End Sub
```

I tried that, and it worked like a charm.  Thanks, everyone, for your help and I hope you find this useful!

Answer (score 1):

I think You have only one problem !
if this Typed dataset has relations between tables, this code won't load the datatables in the correct order !

Comment: OK, I think I see your point (if there is a foreign key constraint and a table requiring that constraint loads first, it won't find any of the data it needs as that table hasn't loaded yet), but I have to say that problem didn't rear its ugly head for the project I was working on (and I had several tables that were joined on several relationships), so maybe .NET did the extra loading for me behind the scenes?  I'll have to debug the code and see if that happens.  +1 for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Mike, for the very thoughtful solution.  Like you, I have been searching for a way to do what you've done, and to use the same mechanism to avoid an ugly switch statement (in C#) that has to case the generated TableAdapters to perform data binding updates.

I converted your VB code to C# as noted below.  I made two changes (I'm using VS Express 2010 and .NET 4.0):

1. I changed the StartWith("tbl") method to EndsWith("TableAdapter") since a number of generated members in the TableAdapters namespace other than just the TableAdapters begin with "tbl" (assuming you want or need to follow that convention anyway), but only the TableAdapters end with "TableAdapter."
2. I changed the call to the Fill method since VS tells me at build time that the object referenced by "adapter" (which does look like a TableAdapter in the debugger) doesn't have a Fill method and there is no Fill extension method.  I therefore cannot perform the Fill.  I'm not at all sure why this didn't work.  But in any case, I changed it to explicitly find the Fill method and then invoke that method.  That seems to work.

Steve

public PopulateDataSet ()
   {

```
// Get the TableAdapters
List<Type> tableAdapters =  (from t in 
              System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()  
              where t.Namespace == "MyNameSpace.m_DataSetTableAdapters" 
              && t.Name.EndsWith("TableAdapter")
              select t).ToList();

// Get the DataTable names
List<string> tableNames = (from DataTable dtbl in m_DataSet.Tables 
               select dtbl.TableName).ToList();

// Loop thru each table and fill it using the corresponding TableAdapter
foreach (string iter in tableNames) 
      {
      string tableName = iter;  // Stopt Linq issues with iteration vbls
      Type adapterType = (from t in tableAdapters
                         where t.Name.StartsWith(tableName)
                         select t).First();

      // Given the adapter type name, use Reflection to create an instance
      Object adapter = Activator.CreateInstance(adapterType);

      // Get a reference to the Fill method of the relevant adapter
      MethodInfo method = adapter.GetType().GetMethod("Fill");

      // Invoke the Fill method, passing in the relevant DataTable parameter
      method.Invoke(adapter, new Object[] {m_DataSet.Tables[tableName]});
      }   

}
```

Comment: Hrm.  This might be one of those cases where VB outshines C# due to the internal plumbing that Just Works(tm).  I see the dilemma: you need to explicitly cast something to the correct type in order to call the method, but of course the type varies here.  About the only thing I can recommend is to declare adapter as type **object** rather than using **var**, but that might not do anything better.  Hmm, I wonder if the fact that you are using VS 2010 express might be part of the problem?  Maybe it doesn't wire up all the internal dataset plumbing the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I've found this thread and since then use this approach with success in my small project. But, recently I've found it out a bit limited. I have few queries for each table adapter in a data set with the names like "FillByContext", "FillById", "FillByName", etc., each one with a different set of parameters of different data types. All methods return tables with the same structure, but with different contents. So that I added some small "generalization" to the approach.

```
Private Sub MethodsAndParams(ds As DataSet,
                             dt As DataTable,
                     taParams() As Object,
                       taMethod As String)
        
        Dim taType As Type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetType(
        "MyProjectName." +
        ds.DataSetName +
        "TableAdapters." +
        dt.TableName +
        "TableAdapter")
        Dim ta As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(taType)
        dt = ds.Tables(dt.TableName)
        ta.GetType().GetMethod(taMethod).Invoke(
    ta, New Object() {dt}.Union(taParams).ToArray)

End Sub
```

Now I can pass table adapter method names as strings and appropriate parameter sets as arrays of objects to this routine.

Comment: I love that this question keeps popping up every few years or so (although it's hard to comprehend that it's been 10 years since it got a comment on).  I have long since moved on from VB and SQL code in general, but this seems like an elegant solution.