# How to create strongly typed dataset programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, strongly-typed-dataset

I have received typed dataset classes in a form of a DLL file. I've imported the file to our project and now I need to programmatically create the dataset and fill the tables with data.

I've already successfully created the TypedDataTable instances and filled them with DataRows. However, when I try to add the tables to the dataset, the dataset simply shows "count 0" for all the tables as if they newer get added.

Is there a way to programmatically add a TypedDataTable to a typed dataset other than reading from an XML file or a database connection (we don't have either)?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738105/net-is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-fill-all-tables-in-a-strongly-typed-da) one of the answers might help.

Comment: I removed the example from the link, as @Fuex highlighted it was not c#.